# Varnish4: need a random integer value

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl, varnish-4

I need a random integer value in Varnish 4.

The std.random() function results in a REAL with three trailing digits.

```
In VCL: 
set req.http.X-AB-test1 = std.random(1,4) 

Observed result: 
X-AB-test1=3.182
```

I would love to find some equivalent to the feature that Fastly offers in its extended VCL: 'randombool()' or even better 'randombool_seeded()'

Thank you!

Comment: I found the function std.real2integer(), but sadly it's not available in EPEL7 Version 4.0.3 -_-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by upgrading to Varnish 4.1 and using the function std.real2integer() like this:

```
set req.http.AB-monitor = std.real2integer(std.random(1,2), 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a solution to generate a/b test values,  [check this solution](https://info.varnish-software.com/blog/live-ab-testing-varnish-and-vcs)

Existing integer values that might help: req.xid, [now](http://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/4.0/reference/vcl.html#now)

Comment: Well, yeah. But I need more then two groups, a simple "if cond A else B" doesn't cut it. ;-)